# The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Recette"} was not handled by any navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to navigate between two screens,  and i don't know what's happening here.
I would like some help please thanks.

**App.js**

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator
                screenOptions={{
                  headerShown: false
              }}
                initialRouteName={'Home'}
            >
                <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}}name="Home" component={Tabs} />
                
                
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}

export default App;`
```

**Home.js**

```
const Home = ({ navigation }) => {

    
    function renderRecetteList() {
        const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
                
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Recette" )}
            >
               
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )

        return (
            <FlatList
                data={recette}
                keyExtractor={item => `${item.id}`}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                contentContainerStyle={{
                    paddingHorizontal: SIZES.padding * 2,
                    paddingBottom: 30
                }}
            />
        )
    }

    return(
        <SafeAreaView style = {styles.container}>
            {renderRecetteList()}
        </SafeAreaView>
        
    )
}
```

**Recette.js**

```
const Recette = ({ navigation }) => {
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>Search</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Recette;
```

The error

> The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Recette"} was not handled by any navigator.

> Do you have a screen named 'Recette'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only navigate to components that are defined as a `Screen` in a react `Navigator`. In order to use `navigate` to go to `Recette` you need to define it as a `Screen` as you did with `Home`.

```js
const App = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator
                screenOptions={{
                  headerShown: false
              }}
                initialRouteName={'Home'}
            >
...
                <Stack.Screen name="Recette" component={Recette} />
                
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```